# N76VZ Network card not recognized by openSUSE

Tags: lan, networkmanager, opensuse-12.2

I have an ASUS N76VZ laptop with openSUSE 12.2. It detects only the wireless card and my Android phone in USB tethering mode. The wired LAN card is detected and works only in Windows.

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fd1 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

I'm using NetworkManager to configure interfaces. YaST network configuration, which can operate only in `ifconfig` mode, detects the card and greys it out ("not configured" under IP column).

How can I enable my wired card on NetworkManager?

[Add]
Ran collectNWData script. It reports an error about wlan0 but I'm not interested in wlan0

```
!!! CND0240E: networkmanager for network configuration enabled but a YAST network card configuration for wlan0 exist
--- Go to http://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/CND#English to get more detailed instructions 
--- about the error/warning messages and how to fix the problems on your own.
```

Full dump at http://pastebin.com/3AKh61va

[Add]
Maybe I've got more info. YaST network configuration, when I switch to ifconfig mode, reports that the `kernel device` for the wired card is not present. "This is usually caused by missing firmware for wlan cards. Check dmesg output".

What do I have to look for in dmesg?

Comment: You can either use ifup/ifconfig or the NetworkManager - not both at the same time. In YaST, you can chose between the two options. Ensure, that the network is in fact managed by NetworkManager. Then configure your card with the NetworkManager in your favourite desktop environment.

Comment: But I see no way of configuring the card in KNetworkManager, the wired connection tab is greyed. Only wireless, VPN and DSL are available. And I **want** to use NetworkManager instead of ifconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install the `alx` driver from source. I can't currently find again web references for it

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a configuration problem of some sort. For diagnosis, please have a look into the following script: [collectNWData](http://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/index.php/collectNWData.sh/collectNWData-Uberblick-/-Overview.html#English). It is designed to investigate your entire network configuration and gives a decent readable output.

Carefully read the manual, download the script, run it, analyse the output - and if in doubt - please post the output here.

Comment: I have pasted the full dump because no meaningful error was reported. But I found interesting things in the dump: it finds the ethernet controller but doesn't report any ifcfg configuration for it. But shouldn't NetworkManager take care of that?